# Rails NoMethodError in Browser but not Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on Chapter 10 at railstutorial.org, having just added the will_paginate gem. When I'm in the rails console, I get the following:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :005 > User.paginate(:page => 1).class
 => WillPaginate::Collection
```

So, here the User class responds to the paginate method. As in the book, I've edited the index method of UsersController to read as follows:

```
def index
  @title = "All users"
  @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

However, when I load the http://localhost:3000/users page (after being logged in, which is confirmed by changing the third line above to retrive User.all), I get a NoMethodError pointing to that third line that assigns the value to @users. The Gemfile adds the will_paginate gem at the top level, not within any group.

How can the User class respond to the paginate method within the console but not within a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding gems, I think it is necessary to restart the rails server.  Did you do so?

Comment: That was it. Thanks. The last time that was necessary in the book they mentioned it. Either they missed or, more likely, I did. :)